# Second sentence with similar meaning to the first one

Tags: sentence

-We had a long discussion about the problem but we couldn't solve it.

-We discussed(length)________ but we couldn't solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: [*ad nauseum*?](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ad+nauseum)

Answer (score 1):

We discussed the problem at length, but we couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

"We discussed at length the problem, but we couldn't solve it"
Or
"We discussed the problem at length, but we couldn't solve it"

The second sentence sounds more natural to me.